# Passing Parameters from Parent Document to External Script Loaded in Child Document in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, parameters, r-markdown, knitr

there is the following script (test.R)

```
# ---- testA ----

data <- tribble(  
  ~sex, ~generation, ~high, ~n,
  "M", 10, "high", 38,
  "M", 10, "low", 148,
  "F", 10, "high", 10,
  "F", 20, "low", 33) 

dat <- 
  data |>
  group_by(!!sym(input_params$attribution)) |>   
  # summarize(hoge) |>  
  pivot_wider( names_from =  input_params$attribution, 
               values_from = "n") |>
  print()


# ---- testB ----

result <- 
  dat |>
  chisq.test() |> 
  print()
```

I will load this script in a child document (child1.Rmd or child2.Rmd).

```
---
title: "child1"
output: html_document
---

``{r, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
``

``{r, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk('test.R')
options(knitr.duplicate.label = "allow")
``


 `r input_params$attribution`

``{r, testA, echo=FALSE}



``
```

```
---
title: "child2"
output: html_document
---

``{r, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
``

``{r, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk('test.R')
options(knitr.duplicate.label = "allow")
``


 `r input_params$attribution`

``{r, testA, echo=FALSE}

data <- tribble( 
  ~sex, ~generation, ~high, ~n,
  "M", 10, "high", 38,
  "M", 10, "low", 148,
  "F", 10, "high", 10,
  "F", 20, "low", 33) 

dat <- 
  data |>
  group_by(!!sym(input_params$attribution)) |>   
  # summarize(hoge) |>  
  pivot_wider( names_from =  input_params$attribution, 
               values_from = "n") |>
  print()


``
```

Afterwards, I configured it as follows in the parent document (parent.Rmd).

```
---
title: "parent"
output: html_document
---

``{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
``


``{r, echo=FALSE}
# param_define
params_df = tibble(attribution = c("sex", "generation"))

res_list <- lapply(1:nrow(params_df),
                  function(x) {
                    input_params <- params_df[x,] 
                    knitr::knit_child('child.Rmd', quiet = TRUE, envir = environment())
                    })
``

``{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:nrow(params_df)) {
  cat(res_list[[i]])
  cat("\n")
}
``
```

I expected parameters (in this case, 'sex' and 'generation') to be passed from the parent document to the child document, reflected in the script loaded within the child document, and to generate results for both 'sex' and 'generation.' In child1.Rmd, only the results for 'sex' are generated, while in child2.Rmd, the desired output is obtained.

I want to knit the parent document and create a document using the format of child1.Rmd. How can I achieve this?